# Bukkit plugin EventHandler registry error

Tags: java, bukkit

I am making a plugin in CraftBukkit 1.8.8, which is a scoreboard that displays information. I am using separate classes for this, so my `onEnable()` is in the Main, while the `PlayerJoin` event is in the `Scoreboard` class.

Here is my code:

```
package me.GMX.Scoreboard;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.DisplaySlot;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Objective;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Score;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.ScoreboardManager;

public class Scoreboard implements CommandExecutor, Listener {
    private Main plugin;

    public Scoreboard(Main plugin)
    {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void PlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event)  //<--this is the event 
    {
        Player p = event.getPlayer();
         Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this.plugin,new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                // Scoreboard things in here.
            }

    }


}
```

Here is the code from my onEnable in my main.

```
public void onEnable(){

    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

    log.log(Level.INFO, String.format(  "[%s] Successfully enabled version %s!", getDescription().getName(), getDescription().getVersion()));

}
```

I am looking for some way to register the `PlayerJoin` event in my `onEnable` so that I don't have to type a command in order for this plugin to work. I know that this snippet of code:

```
Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this.plugin);
```

Is used to register an event in the same class as it. But my problem is that this plugin is not going to have any commands, and will just be a plugin. I'm not sure how to get this to work, any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `onCommand` if it's unused. Change to:

```
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, new Scoreboard(this));
```

This will construct a listener and register that. Make sure to import the custom class `Scoreboard` instead of constructing the wrong one.